# Safari is overwriting certain page elements like background colours and text. How do I stop it?

Tags: html, css, background, safari

This page renders correctly in every other common browser except Safari. (Yes, it's a mess, I haven't finished the site yet) Safari quickly displays certain elements, then replaces them with white. In particular background images (or colors) in the body tag and , also text in a paragraph tag.

http://sr.hi-speedinter.net/staging/

Yet similar code works on the homepage http://sr.hi-speedinter.net where the body background image displays correctly.

I'm baffled! I've searched for about 2 hours and tried lots of tweaks but nothing has had any effect.

Here's some of the CSS

```
body.src-sub-page {
  background: url("http://sr.hi-speedinter.net/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen-child/images/sub_page_bg_tile.jpg");
  background-color: #edeff3;
  background-position: top;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

.src-sub-page .site-main {
  background-image: url("http://sr.hi-speedinter.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/SRC_InternalPage_Graphic.png");
  background-position: top center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Did you search for Safari bugs? And what happens if you disbale the rest of the CSS?

Is JPG and PNG not working?

Did you try `background` instead of `background-color`?

Did you try it on another PC?

Also try to change these

```
http://sr.hi-speedinter.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/SRC_InternalPage_Graphic.png"
```

to

```
wp-content/uploads/2015/02/SRC_InternalPage_Graphic.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Gintoki, I had actually tried most of those, but the real problem turned out to be Safari for PC. I found someone nearby with Safari on a MAC and the page worked perfectly.

But for anyone else having similar issues, I highly recommend trying those steps above. Good to have it in one list!